# How do I perform operations using units?

Tags: 3d-view

For example, if my document is set to metric units, and I want to extrude something by 4mm, is there a way I can just type "4mm" instead of having to multiply it in my head to "0.04"? For example, maybe there's an addon that lets me do this?

Comment: You can set the scene units to millimiters by entering 0,001 in Scale in the Scene Units setup.

Comment: if you extrude a face, just after pressing E, you are now grabbing. If you extrude over local or global axis, you can cancel the grab and then set the new "final position" of that "grab", over that axis, editing in the properties panel the relevant "median" value. Eg, if using metric with scale 1, if you find median "1" it means "1 meter", so you can set "1m+mm" and it will become "1.004"